# PouchDB live:true makes initial sync 10 times the size of live:false

Tags: synchronization, cloudant, pouchdb

I am in the middle of building a PouchDB based app that syncs with Cloudant. 
Does anyone know why LIVE:TRUE causes 10 times the downloads as LIVE:FALSE ??

When I run:

> var sync = PouchDB.sync(cloudantDB, localDB, {live: true})

it causes 999+ resources to download, over 4 MB of stuff

But when I run:

> var sync = PouchDB.sync(cloudantDB, localDB, {live: false})

it causes a about 79 resources to download, for a total of about 470 KB

This database only has 4 small docs in it. Any clues would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

I would start by running [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to inspect the traffic. If you're using SSL, you can install your private key into Wireshark so it can [decrypt the packets](http://blogs.technet.com/b/nettracer/archive/2013/10/12/decrypting-ssl-tls-sessions-with-wireshark-reloaded.aspx).

I'd be interested to know your findings.

Comment: The only way you'd identify this is by inspecting the protocol to discover what REST calls are being made.  The way to do that is using Wireshark.  Have you done this?

Comment: You may find that your version of PouchDb has only been tested with a recent CouchDb - not Cloudant's variation of CouchDb. As I recall .. Cloudant is branched from CouchDb 1.0.2 .  So you can perhaps test your PouchDb code against a more recent version of CouchDb (e.g. 1.6.1)

Comment: You'll most likely find that the HTTP response codes differ - hence Wireshark inspection required to diagnose this.